# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) on Windows.Forms

Tags: windows, forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, energy

I would like to write and application that would be working only on Windows 10 and future versions. I was trying a way to be able to connect to HM-10 (BLE module) **without using UWP (Universal Windows)** I could write a code in C#, WPF and I would like it to be a Windows.Forms app.

I did code a windows.forms already that is communicating with older Bluetooth devices (not low energy), but I am now forced to upgrade that Bluetooth module to a BLE one and update the app. I cannot move to UWP because I'd like to use a transparent window feature, global hotkeys and user activity (User32.dll libs) which aren't supported in UWP.

Are there any samples or any hints? I've spend likely 10 hours during weekend trying to find a way how to do it. I was working on Visual Studio 2015.

Thank you

Comment: You can use the same libraries as you use in a WPF app when you write a Windows.Forms app. Just add references to the correct libraries. Could you tell what the problems are?

Comment: I was already trying to get that done, but I could not get references from the WPF app. Do you know how to do that? Aren't there any examples?